# Excel vba - Format isn't copied to other cell

Tags: excel, vba

I got an excel file with an autoincrement on 1 cell, where the numberformat is "000".

```
Worksheets("TEST").Range("M17").Value = Worksheets("TEST").Range("M17").Value + 1
Worksheets("TEST").Range("M17").NumberFormat = "000"
```

This works fine, so my first number is: 001 instead of 1.

Now I need to merge this cell to another cell M16 (which displays an input for example: 2020)

```
=M16&"/"&M17
```

But for some reason it is losing his NumberFormat, and excel is showing: 2020/1 instead of 2020/001.

I have tried several things, like formatting my cell M18

```
Worksheets("TEST").Range("M18").NumberFormat = "0000/000"
```

Or by trying to solve this directly in vba

```
Worksheets("TEST").Range("M18").Value = Worksheets("FACTUUR").Range("M16").Value & Worksheets("TEST").Range("M17").Value
Worksheets("TEST").Range("M18").NumberFormat = "0000/000"
```

Or even by changing the format from within Excel itself, but then I get an error message directly (don't know why...)

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Use `Format$` when concatenating.

Comment: Does `=1/2` show as `0,5` or as `0.5` on your excel version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on an excel application configured to work with decimal comma instead of decimal point.

Therefore the formula you type in the cell should have a semicolon

```
=M16&"/"&TEXT(M17;"000")
```

Note that the same formula can be assigned to the cell in VBA with a comma:

```
Range("M18").Formula="=M16&""/""&TEXT(M17,""000"")"
```

:(

Comment: Thanks!  I can't believe that this was my problem, and most that I didn't found it myself :p  Thanks for the help again. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your code only changes the way the number is displayed to the user. If you click into cell M17 after running your code, you will see that the actual value is simply 1 and not 001. You need to use format$ as BigBen suggested earlier and then concatenate as per the code below:

```
    Worksheets("test").range("M17").value = Worksheets("test").range("M17").value + 1
    Worksheets("test").range("M17").NumberFormat = "000"

    Dim firstValue As String: firstValue = Worksheets("test").range("M16").value
    Dim secondValue As String: secondValue = 
    Format$(Worksheets("test").range("M17").value, "000")
    Worksheets("test").range("M18").value = firstValue & "/" & secondValue
```

Comment: The disadvantages of this solution is, that you need to trigger VBA code each time the user edits the sheet.